# stm32f411 HAL ssd1289

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, hal

Im struggling with ssd1289@ stm32f411v some time . I have problem with refreshing data on screen . Changes on variable like temperature from bmp180 etc  seems to be not refreshes . Strings on screen are putted one on another without clearing background. I wrote function cleaning whole screen but its to slow and screen starts blinking :

```
void LCD_Clear(void) {
     uint32_t i = 0;
     LCD_SetWindow(0,0,320,240);
     LCD_write_command(0x0022);
     for (i = 0; i < 320*240; i++) { LCD_write_data(0x0000); }
}
```

I try use timers interrupts  with 65Hz refreshing and lower freq ::

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
      if ( htim ->Instance == TIM3 ){
         LCD_Clear();
         LCD_PutStr(10,30,temperature,RGB565(255,192,255));
         LCD_PutStr(60,30,pressure,RGB565(255,192,255));
      }
}
```

and on debugging i have  error :

> Info : The target is not running when halt was requested, stopping GDB.

When i remove LCD_Clear(); from timfunction i have symptoms as described on beginning.

Any ideas what is wrong .

Comment: Your interrupt handler execution time is much too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS PeterJ_01 says : execution time is much too long .

In interruption i dont clear whole screen only partial :)